# Highchart error 16 occured for calling charts more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I have three html page  containing two charts(BAR,PIE) in two tabs. when i run the pages individually it works fine but when i call the pages from home page first page loaded fine but after loading first page when i load the second page from home page i got error:

page1.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/chart/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
```

i include the same script in page2.html and when load in from home page page1 loaded fine then i click page2 and the following error occured:

> uncaught exception: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

i know this is happening for calling highcharts more than once but don't know
how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call the pages from home page ' ?

Comment: Just add Highcharts scripts on a home page, not for each of tab-pages.

Comment: I mean to say i go the page reference from home or index page by clicking link@SteveP

Comment: I also try with this but got this error TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function @PawełFus

Comment: It means that highcharts.js are not loaded or jquery is missing.